# Appending list(element) to another list gives an element by letter

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Sorry for this question, but I do not understand why the difference between the following results when adding an element to the list as a list itself to other list:

```
list_a=[]
list_b=['HELLO','WORLD']
for word in list_b:
    list_a.append([word])
print("Append to dist_list single word: ", list_a)
```

```
Output: Append to list_a:  [['HELLO'], ['WORLD']]
```

```
list_a=[]
list_b=['HELLO','WORLD']
for word in list_b:
    list_a.append(list(word))
print("Append to list_a: ", list_a)
```

```
output: Append to list_a:  [['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'], ['W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']]
```

Comment: There are no spaces in this result. The difference is that `list(word)` and `[word]` do not mean the same thing.

Comment: `list()` accepts iterator, in the case of `list('HELLO')` you will get list of separate characters. In the case of `['HELLO']` you will get list containing one string.

Comment: Yes. Why are you doing this? Why not just `list_a.append(word)`?

Comment: might you be looking for `extend`?

Comment: Sorry, I stated the title wrongly, each letter becomes an element in the list instead of the whole word would become an element. I am doing this because I have a process after that takes a list of lists. Usually, the result would be `[['Hello','world'],['Hola','mundo']]`, but sometimes I will get just `[['Hello','World']]` like in the example. I am adding to another list to fulfill requirements of the following process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `list()` to a string, the string gets turned into a list that's separated for each individual value. For example:

```
a = 'string'
b = list(a) 
b = ['s','t','r','i','n','g']
```

Therefore the difference comes because in the first case you are appending two items (both being strings) and in the second one, you are appending the string previously turned into a list with the logic explained above, hence you've appended a list for each string. This is the differnece in the results you are getting. First case add two strings, second case add two lists.